# Debug RestClass Salesforce for Site Guest User

Tags: force.com, force.com-sites, apexrest

I am facing this issue.Setting cookies in browser is creating debug only when site is open from url but not when this class get post request from webhook third party.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue before, where the GuestSite user is not properly writing back to debug logs. I worked around it by sending an email via apex to myself with the debug content to get around it.